# Configuring for WifI Concurrent Mode result in DNS Issue for networking

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I was trying to configure for my Raspberry to be client and access point mode when I run into problem of access the web and even apt-get update

This is the diagnostic that I have done:

First i try to ping 8.8.8.8 which is a nameserver

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=3.91 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=3.83 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=3.65 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.651/3.795/3.909/0.118 ms
```

but on pinging google.com

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping -c3 google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

looking at my /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

what could go wrong?

Thanks

====================================================================
Edit:

Output when running *systemctl status systemd-resolved.service*

```
systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.d
           └─resolvconf.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-10-31 16:59:40 +08; 27min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/resolved
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
           https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
  Process: 571 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /run/resolvconf/enable-updates ] || echo "nameserver 127.0.0.53" | /sbin/resolvconf -a systemd-resolved (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 539 (systemd-resolve)
   Status: "Processing requests..."
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 1939)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
           └─539 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question org IN DNSKEY: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question pool.ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question pool.ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question debian.pool.ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question debian.pool.ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 1.debian.pool.ntp.org IN DS: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 1.debian.pool.ntp.org IN SOA: signature-expired
Oct 31 17:27:36 raspberrypi systemd-resolved[539]: DNSSEC validation failed for question 1.debian.pool.ntp.org IN A: signature-expired
```

Output when running: resolvctl

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.101
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.101
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (uap0)
      Current Scopes: LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.101
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.101
          DNS Domain: ~.

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.101
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.101
```

**UPDATE** with info from comments:
Manage to fixed the sudo apt-get problem.... it is some problem to with settig of the dns server but i stil did not manage to get the concurrent mode to work... so far i am only being able to get the raspberry pi to connect to ethernet via etho and uap0 as my hotspot... any hp that connect to uap0 can get access to internet...but once once the lan cable is pulled out...there is no internet access.

I am using raspbian buster as OS. I am planning to use uap0 as the Wifi hotspot for my handphone (aka hp) to connect to recieve wifi connection and to access internet. wlan0 and uap0 uses the internal raspberry wifi card. eth0 will connect to the router but i am hoping that if eth0 is not connected, wlan0 will take over this task (or simply wlan0 will take this task, I am planning to take pi setup elsewhere where physical connection ie ethernet cable is not available).

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/117973/edit) your question and add the output of these two commands to it: `systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` and `resolvectl`.

Comment: @Ingo. Manage to fixed the sudo apt-get problem.... it is some problem to with settig of the dns server but i stil did not manage to get the concurrent mode to work... so far i am only being able to get the raspberry pi to connect to ethernet via etho and uap0 as my hotspot... any hp that connect to uap0 can get access to internet...but once once the lan cable is pulled out...there is no internet access

Comment: The lan cable connected to the internet router. Pulling it out will of course break the internet access. That is as expected. What's the problem?

Comment: As far as I see you are using `systemd-resolved` and there is a known problem with DNSSEC. Do you also use `systemd-networkd`? What operating system do you use? How do you configure the access point with interface **uap0**? You are using **eth0** as client uplink to an internet router. For what do you use interface **wlan0**? What is hp?

Comment: @Ingo I am using raspbian buster as OS. I am planning to use uap0 as the Wifi hotspot for my handphone (aka hp) to connect to recieve wifi connection and to access internet.  wlan0 and uap0 uses the internal raspberry wifi card. eth0 will connect to the router but i am hoping that if eth0 is not connected, wlan0 will take over this task (or simply wlan0 will take this task, I am planning to take pi setup elsewhere where physical connection ie ethernet cable is not available)

Comment: The title is "*DNS Issue for networking*". This and the question does not really reflect your problem. Can you please change that an elaborate the question to better match your problem?